# Enforce explicit node creation (dot, graphviz)

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am working on a big graph with lots of nodes which is rendered in dot `dot -Tsvg graph.gv -o graph.svg`.
To keep the overview I "explicitly" define all nodes I use at the begin of the graph.

Now I am searching for a way to make sure that only those "explicitly" defined nodes are used and I don't get "implicitly" created nodes on an edge definition (e.g. typo in the node name).

The rendering of the following graph should not work or warn me on rendering that an "implicit" node is used.

```
graph main_graph {

  // explicit node definition
  node1[style=filled, color=grey];
  node2[style=filled, color=grey];
  node3[style=filled, color=grey];

  subgraph graph1 {
    edge [color=red,penwidth=2]
    node0 -- node2; //node0 implicitly defined
  }

  subgraph graph2 {
    edge [color="blue",penwidth=2]
    node2 -- node3;
    node1 -- node3;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official support does not exist.

I used the tip like the followings.

**1. Add mark for implicit node**

```
graph main_graph {

  // explicit node definition
  node1[style=filled, color=grey];
  node2[style=filled, color=grey];
  node3[style=filled, color=grey];

  // ---- lower boundary of explicit node definition ----
  // default node attribute used for the detection of implicit node definition
  node[label="IMPLICITLY-DEFINED"]

  subgraph graph1 {
    edge [color=red,penwidth=2]
    node0 -- node2; //node0 implicitly defined
  }

  subgraph graph2 {
    edge [color="blue",penwidth=2]
    node2 -- node3;
    node1 -- node3;
  }
}
```

**2. Find the marks for the implicitly defined node**

```
$ dot -Tplain graph.gv | awk '/IMPLICITLY-DEFINED/{print $2}'
node0
```

Tested version: graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304) on macOS

Comment: Seems like a good workaround, I'll keep it open for the weekend s to check for other ideas and then accept the best answer.